# Python keywords role

Tags: python, keyword

I have looked on the web to find a list of all Python keywords along with what they do, however I can only find the list of the keywords without an explanation of what they do. Example: http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/ref/keywords.html. So basically, if I want to know what a keyword does I have to look for it on the web. While this is not much trouble, I believe there must be a source somewhere where all this information has been grouped up, speeding up the keyword learning process.

So I would like to know if someone here might refer me to a website where I can find all this information.

Thanks !

Comment: Just read through [the expressions part](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html) of the documentation.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are limited to using python 2.3?

Comment: You're looking at documentation from 7 years ago. Python has changed a lot since then.

Comment: My guess is you probably won't find what exactly what you're looking for because your approach to learning the language is not how most folks do it -- hence there's little demand for such a thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strangely enough it's the [first result](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pythontutorial/keywords/) on a google search for [python keywords and explanations](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=python+keywords+and+explanations&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).

Comment: I think this would be better as a comment than an answer.

Comment: @senderle I beleive the opposite. It answers precisely the question.

Comment: By looking closely at the website, it does have what I was looking for. The layout of the website simply made me run away the first time I went on it. Thanks :)

Comment: @senderle I agree. Although the problem would be in the question itself.

Answer (score 5):

In the [python interpreter](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html) prompt:

```
>>> help()

[OMITTED LINES FOR BREVITY]

To get a list of available modules, keywords, or topics, type "modules",
"keywords", or "topics".  Each module also comes with a one-line summary
of what it does; to list the modules whose summaries contain a given word
such as "spam", type "modules spam".

help> keywords

Here is a list of the Python keywords.  Enter any keyword to get more help.

and                 elif                if                  print
as                  else                import              raise
assert              except              in                  return
break               exec                is                  try
class               finally             lambda              while
continue            for                 not                 with
def                 from                or                  yield
del                 global              pass                

help>
```

Now to get information about e.g. break, just type "break" followed by enter.

Also, if you need information about the keywords of the python version you're running at the moment (e.g. is `yield` a keyword in my python version?), there's the [keyword module](http://docs.python.org/library/keyword.html):

```
>>> from keyword import kwlist, iskeyword
>>> kwlist
['and', 'as', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def', 'del', 'elif', 
'else', 'except', 'exec', 'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 
'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'print', 'raise', 'return', 'try', 
'while', 'with', 'yield']
>>> iskeyword("and")
True
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending if documentation was installed with your distribution of Python, you can access keyword information through the interactive help menu directly in the python interpreter:

```
>>> help()

Welcome to Python 2.7!  This is the online help utility.

...

To get a list of available modules, keywords, or topics, type "modules",
"keywords", or "topics".  Each module also comes with a one-line summary
of what it does; to list the modules whose summaries contain a given word
such as "spam", type "modules spam".

help> keywords

Here is a list of the Python keywords.  Enter any keyword to get more help.

and                 elif                if                  print
as                  else                import              raise
assert              except              in                  return
break               exec                is                  try
class               finally             lambda              while
continue            for                 not                 with
def                 from                or                  yield
del                 global              pass

help> and
Boolean operations
******************

...

The expression ``x and y`` first evaluates *x*; if *x* is false, its
value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value
is returned.
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) covers the Python language and its keywords. It explains the language from basic to advanced which is useful for beginners (e.g., starting from the basic `if` and `else` to the more advanced `lambda` and `yield`).

Answer (score 1):

The [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/) discusses the structure and syntax of Python. All of these keywords are discussed in here somewhere, just look through the table of contents, though not all collected into a single list.